# Fiware iot agent error on creating service and registration

Tags: fiware

i am a fiware user and i have created an iot agent on an ubuntu 14.04 empty vm and when i send a create service or a device registration request ,  i get an error. And i've made sure that the ports listen properly and i've also allowed tcp connection on the port 4061. and also get an error whenever i send the reuest .

here's the create service request

```
(curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'fiware-service: bla770' -H 'fiware-servicepath: /howtobla770' -X POST 'http://217.172.12.243:4061/iot/services' -d @- ) << EOF
{
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "api70",
            "token": "token",
            "cbroker": "http://147.27.60.58:1026",
            "resource": "/iot/d",
            "entity_type": "thing"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

and this is the error which i get .

```
connect to 217.172.12.243 port 4061 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 217.172.12.243 port 4061: Connection timed out
```

Although i have allowed  the port 4061 through the firewall by the command 
sudo ufw allow 4061

Comment: Did you do the port forwarding at your VM? If you did without success, maybe you can try this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/ .

Comment: why i need port forwarding ?? @Dalton

Comment: maybe because you are facing connection problem?! It seems to be clearly a network configuration problem!

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary adding a security rule opening port 4061 in your Security Groups (cloud portal).

Comment: i allready add the security group to open the port in cloud portal   TCP  4061  4061  0.0.0.0/0 (CIDR)